# Placing the footer out of view using CSS grid

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I have a header that is 70px high, the main content which I want to fill the rest of the screen and then a 70px footer. *I am trying to find the most simple approach of hiding a footer.* This works with the *footer* in view - see [**`jsfiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/odb7xp4a/) and snippet below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: [side__nav] 250px [main] 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: [header] 70px auto [footer] 70px;
}

.header {
  grid-column: main;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: pink;
}

.side__nav {
  grid-column: side__nav;
  grid-row: 1/span 3;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  grid-column: main;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: green;
}

.footer {
  grid-column: main;
  grid-row: 3;
  background: purple;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.a {
  grid-column: col/span 2;
  grid-row: row;
}

.b {
  grid-column: col 3/span 2;
  grid-row: row;
}

.c {
  grid-column: col/span 2;
  grid-row: row 2;
}

.d {
  grid-column: col 3/span 2;
  grid-row: row 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.e {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.f {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.g {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">header</header>
<nav class="side__nav">side__nav</nav>
<content class="content">content</content>
<footer class="footer">footer</footer>
```

---

But I want to push it off screen so I can use a button to show when needed. I have tried using `grid-template-rows: [header] 70px calc(100vh - 70px) [footer] 70px`
which does give me the effect I want see [**`jsfiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/gywfatkL/5/) and snippet below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: [side__nav] 250px [main] 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: [header] 70px calc(100vh - 70px) [footer] 70px;
}

.header {
  grid-column: main;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: pink;
}

.side__nav {
  grid-column: side__nav;
  grid-row: 1/span 3;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  grid-column: main;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: green;
}

.footer {
  grid-column: main;
  grid-row: 3;
  background: purple;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.a {
  grid-column: col/span 2;
  grid-row: row;
}

.b {
  grid-column: col 3/span 2;
  grid-row: row;
}

.c {
  grid-column: col/span 2;
  grid-row: row 2;
}

.d {
  grid-column: col 3/span 2;
  grid-row: row 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.e {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.f {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.g {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">header</header>
<nav class="side__nav">side__nav</nav>
<content class="content">content</content>
<footer class="footer">footer</footer>
```

> But the problem with that is, If I use `grid-gap: 10px` I have to
>   calculate that in `grid-template-rows` which then gets messy if I add
>   more sections.

For instance, 3 sections will have 2 gaps, if I set the gap as 10px, the total will be 20px, plus the 70px for the footer meaning a total of 90px. If someone takes over the code they need to know that they need to add this manually to the `grid-template-row` line which I know will get missed. Anyone have a simple idea that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove your `footer` from the *explicit grid* (change your *explicit grid* row definition into `grid-template-rows: [header] 70px 1fr` and remove `grid-row: 3` from `footer`) and set the *grid container* height to `calc(100vh + 70px)` and set the *implicit grid row* (which is your `footer` height) using `grid-auto-rows: 70px`.

See demo below with *vanilla CSS*:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: calc(100vh + 70px); /* adding footer height */
  grid-template-columns: [side__nav] 250px [main] 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: [header] 70px 1fr; /* removed footer from here */
  grid-auto-rows: 70px; /* implicit grid height - footer height */
}

.header {
  grid-column: main;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: pink;
}

.side__nav {
  grid-column: side__nav;
  grid-row: 1/span 3;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  grid-column: main;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: green;
}

.footer {
  grid-column: main;
  /*grid-row: 3;*/
  background: purple;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.a {
  grid-column: col/span 2;
  grid-row: row;
}

.b {
  grid-column: col 3/span 2;
  grid-row: row;
}

.c {
  grid-column: col/span 2;
  grid-row: row 2;
}

.d {
  grid-column: col 3/span 2;
  grid-row: row 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.e {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.f {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.g {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">header</header>
<nav class="side__nav">side__nav</nav>
<content class="content">content</content>
<footer class="footer">footer</footer>
```

But again you'll have to do those *messy calculations* when new sections are added to the grid. A more *dynamic option* is to keep a *grid item* (zero-width `adjuster` element in demo below) just for setting the layout height:

- placed in the first column and *spanned across* the first two rows
- has `height: 100vh` set and pushed behind with `z-index: -1` so that it doesn't affect the layout.

See demo below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: [side__nav] 250px [main] 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: [header] 70px 1fr; /* removed footer from here */
  grid-auto-rows: 70px; /* implicit grid height - footer height */
}

.header {
  grid-column: main;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: pink;
}

.side__nav {
  grid-column: side__nav;
  grid-row: 1/span 3;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  grid-column: main;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: green;
}

.footer {
  grid-column: main;
  /*grid-row: 3;*/
  background: purple;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.a {
  grid-column: col/span 2;
  grid-row: row;
}

.b {
  grid-column: col 3/span 2;
  grid-row: row;
}

.c {
  grid-column: col/span 2;
  grid-row: row 2;
}

.d {
  grid-column: col 3/span 2;
  grid-row: row 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.e {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.f {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.g {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.adjuster { /* grid items spanning two rows with explicit height set */
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  height: 100vh;
}

section { /* new sections added*/
  background: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">header</header>
<nav class="side__nav">side__nav</nav>
<content class="content">content</content>
<footer class="footer">footer</footer>
<!-- height adjuster for viewport -->
<span class="adjuster"></span>
<!-- other page sections below -->
<section></section>
<section></section>
```

Excerpts on *implicit* and *explicit* grids from MDN:

> [**`The implicit and explicit grid (MDN)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#The_implicit_and_explicit_grid)
>
> If you place something outside of the defined grid—or due to the
>   amount of content, more grid tracks are needed—then the grid creates
>   rows and columns in the *implicit grid*. These tracks will be auto-sized
>   by default, resulting in their size being based on the content that is
>   inside them.
>
> You can also define a set size for tracks created in the implicit grid
>   with the `grid-auto-rows` and `grid-auto-columns` properties.

---

You can read more about *Explicit and Implicit Grids* here: [CSS Grid unwanted column added automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956781)

Comment: Almost but not quite. Using grid-gap: 10px; give you a nice gap between the grids and it works as needed. The issue comes when you add margin:10px; on the body to give you that same gap around the edges to match the grid-gap. When doing this, you lose the gap at the bottom. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/gywfatkL/6/

Comment: adjust for the `margin` - you can make your *grid-container* `height: calc(100vh + 70px - 10px)` see https://jsfiddle.net/2xnyktrg/

Comment: @Juan-man have updated answer with a better approach - see https://jsfiddle.net/my4et6j7/ and after adding `margin` to the *grid container*: https://jsfiddle.net/enjotp9q/