# How to make auto-placed divs via grid-auto-flow:column stick to each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I want to make timeline that will contain divs representing periods of time. I encountered trouble. When using `grid-auto-flow: column` to make all divs horizontal the gaps between divs are very big.

```css
.timelineBox {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.timelineBox>.timeline>div.main {
  height: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0px;
}

._1 {
  background-color: red;
}

._2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

._3 {
  background-color: lime;
}

._4 {
  background-color: purple;
}

.timelineBox>.timeline>div.main>div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='timelineBox'>
  <div ident='tl1' class='timeline'>
    <div class='main'>
      <div style='width: 5px;' class='_1'>
      </div>
      <div style='width: 120px;' class='_2'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to make this gap be smaller without resizing parent div?

---

**TD;DR**: How to make divs *stick* to each other when using `grid-auto-flow: column`?

Comment: `justify-content: flex-start;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `justify-content: flex-start` to align all the *grid items* to the left of the *grid container* - see demo below:

```css
.timelineBox {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.timelineBox>.timeline>div.main {
  height: 50px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0px;
}

._1 {
  background-color: red;
}

._2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

._3 {
  background-color: lime;
}

._4 {
  background-color: purple;
}

.timelineBox>.timeline>div.main>div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='timelineBox'>
  <div ident='tl1' class='timeline'>
    <div class='main'>
      <div style='width: 5px;' class='_1'></div>
      <div style='width: 120px;' class='_2'></div>
      <div style='width: 5px;' class='_1'></div>
      <div style='width: 120px;' class='_2'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Implicit Grids

But you have more options here - because and you have not specified `grid-template-columns` property you are dealing with *implicit grids* here. The *computed* width of *grid items* that you are seeing is due to the default `grid-auto-columns: auto` property, which handles the sizing of *grid columns* for *implicit grids*.

So you can specify `grid-auto-columns: min-content` like below to achieve the same result:

```css
.timelineBox {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.timelineBox>.timeline>div.main {
  height: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: min-content; /* ADDED */
  grid-gap: 0px;
}

._1 {
  background-color: red;
}

._2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

._3 {
  background-color: lime;
}

._4 {
  background-color: purple;
}

.timelineBox>.timeline>div.main>div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='timelineBox'>
  <div ident='tl1' class='timeline'>
    <div class='main'>
      <div style='width: 5px;' class='_1'></div>
      <div style='width: 120px;' class='_2'></div>
      <div style='width: 5px;' class='_1'></div>
      <div style='width: 120px;' class='_2'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about [**`Implicit and Explicit Grids here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298508/placing-the-footer-out-of-view-using-css-grid/55298820#55298820).

---

#### Inline Grids

Another option use an *inline-grid* - the *auto placement of grid items* will now take only as much width as its contents:

```css
.timelineBox {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.timelineBox>.timeline>div.main {
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-grid; /* changed to inline*/
  vertical-align: top; /* align inline element */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0px;
}

._1 {
  background-color: red;
}

._2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

._3 {
  background-color: lime;
}

._4 {
  background-color: purple;
}

.timelineBox>.timeline>div.main>div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='timelineBox'>
  <div ident='tl1' class='timeline'>
    <div class='main'>
      <div style='width: 5px;' class='_1'></div>
      <div style='width: 120px;' class='_2'></div>
      <div style='width: 5px;' class='_1'></div>
      <div style='width: 120px;' class='_2'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see a nice [**`example of using inline grids here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55309569/css-grid-problem-with-background-and-wrapping/55324190#55324190).

Comment: Thanks. Very full answer. I knew about `min-content`, because I was doing the same thing about a year ago. Just forgot, that it exists :) Again. Thank you.