# grid-auto-columns: 50px 50px 20px; without template or grid-area

Tags: css, css-grid

For me it's very counterintuitive that as soon as I remove `grid-area` the `grid-auto-columns: 50px 50px 20px;` doesn't divide the container in 3 columns `50px 50px 20px`. You have to force a `grid-area` on it before you get 3 columns. Without you get a single column. Why is that? Why did they design it that way?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 20px 50px;
  grid-auto-columns: 50px 50px 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.area {
  grid-area: 1/1/1/4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div class="area">5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 20px 50px;
  grid-auto-columns: 50px 50px 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.area {
  grid-area: 1/1/1/4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe what you want is `grid-template-columns` instead of `grid-auto-colums`

Comment: more resources for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298508 and a nice application of implicit grids here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55309569

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the [default flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) is `row` and there is no **explicit** column defined nor **implicit** ones so you will have one column and as many rows as items.

You can achieve what you want by setting `grid-template-columns` instead of `grid-auto-columns` that will explicitely define the columns (3 in your case).

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 20px 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.area {
  grid-area: 1/1/1/4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

And if you change the flow to column you will have this:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 20px 50px;
  grid-auto-columns: 50px 50px 20px;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

You will notice a similar issue for the row direction (no explict/implicit rows = 1 row and n columns) that you can *fix* with a `grid-template-rows` that will explicitely specify the rows:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20px 50px;
  grid-auto-columns: 50px 50px 20px;
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

---

> The grid-auto-columns CSS property specifies the size of an **implicitly-created** grid column track.
>
> If a grid item is positioned into a column that is not explicitly sized by grid-template-columns, implicit grid tracks are created to hold it. This can happen either by **explicitly positioning into a column that is out of range**, or by the **auto-placement algorithm creating additional columns**. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns)</sup>

As you can read, `grid-auto-columns` is only used when there is implicit grid track created by *manually* placing the items (like you did) or by changing the auto-placement algorithm (like I did). Same logic happen for the row direction but since the default flow is `row` it's more intuitive.

Basically `grid-auto-[rows|columns]` are useful to ensure that extra (implicit) row/column created will follow a specific pattern.

Example with a row flow:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  /*our explicit grid 4x4 */
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  /**/
  grid-auto-columns: 20px; /*extra columns will have 20px*/
  grid-auto-rows: 40px; /*extra rows will have 40px*/
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div style="grid-column:3">I am creating an implicit column</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

and with column flow:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  /*our explicit grid 4x4 */
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  /**/
  grid-auto-columns: 20px; /*extra columns will have 20px*/
  grid-auto-rows: 40px; /*extra rows will have 40px*/
  grid-auto-flow:column;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div style="grid-row:3">I am creating an implicit row</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks your examples makes it look consistent. Guess it just one of does IQ things where you need to be a little bit smarter than me to understand the pattern :) But you explained it well.

Comment: @GertCuykens added more details and examples ;)